# Standalone file in root to create a category attribute:

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Hi I am trying to create a file in root of magento installation to add a category attribute. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');  // Include Mage files
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID)); //Set admin store id
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label'=> 'New Product Name For Categories',
    'input' => 'select',
    'default' => array(0),
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' =>  '',
    'position'            => 100,
    'group' => 'General Information'  // Choose Group
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'name_for_categories', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$installer->startSetup();` remove this  tested and working..

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
    $installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
    $attribute  = array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label'=> 'New Product Name For Categories',
        'input' => 'select',
        'default' => array(0),
        'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' =>  '',
        'position'            => 100,
        'group' => 'General Information'  // Choose Group
    );

    $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'ATTRIBUTECODE', $attribute);
    $installer->endSetup();
```

for deleting the attribute tested and working.

```
<?php 
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'ATTRIBUTECODE');


$installer->endSetup();
?>
```

to check the attribute value in every category

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categories as $category) {


    $cat = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category->getId());

    var_dump($cat->getData()); // Gives result


}
```

Comment: Great your method is working. but how do i remove the attribute now?  I have a following code <?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category','name_for_categories');

Comment: update the answer kindly check also tested..

Comment: Great, That is working as well.

Comment: Also is there a quick way to get that attribute?

Comment: update the answer

Comment: Not printing the custom attribute.

Comment: kindly do the index management...

Comment: That was it, Thanks. I am using an unorthodox method but its doing the job: $category = Mage::getModel(‘catalog/category’)->load(10);

$attribute = Mage::getSingleton(‘eav/config’)->getAttribute(‘catalog_category’, ‘myattribute_code’);

$text = $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($category->getMyattributeCode());

Comment: Hi again how to add another 'text' attribute?

Comment: $attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'Bottom Description',
    'input' => 'text',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);

this will do it

Comment: Alright its working how to retrieve it ?

Comment: same procedure for retrieve.

Comment: Not printing anything even after re indexing.

Comment: Mage::getModel(‘catalog/category’)->load(10); 
$category->getMyattributeCode()

this will show that..

Comment: next time ask the separate question so community can get help too..

Comment: If i ask separate question my question will be either labeled duplicate, similar or something else.

Comment: yeah happens a lots.. u r right

Answer (score 3):

Inchoo published a great article on adding attributes to categories which you can find here: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-new-custom-category-attribute-in-magento/.

The most important part is the installer.

```
$installer = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup();
$installer->startSetup();

$entityTypeId     = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_category');
$attributeSetId   = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
$attributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId);

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'new_cat_attrb',  array(
    'type'     => 'int',
    'label'    => 'New Category Attribute',
    'input'    => 'text',
    'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => false,
    'default'           => 0
));


$installer->addAttributeToGroup(
    $entityTypeId,
    $attributeSetId,
    $attributeGroupId,
    'new_cat_attrb',
    '11' //last Magento's attribute position in General tab is 10
);

$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, 'new_cat_attrb');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Alright I ran the file but i don't see any new attributes in category?

Comment: Updated my answer. Misread what you actually wanted to try. Please see above code

Comment: Still don't see any new attributes.

Comment: @mysticalghoul please turn on error reporting, check Magento logs for errors etc to debug. It's hard to determine what's wrong remotely

Comment: i have an extension installed that will show if there is any existing new attribute. its empty.

Answer (score 1):

Really you should build a module for this. If modules are new to you then use:

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

You can specify an install script with this, in the install script you can also set it to remove your attribute if it already exists before adding it back in again. In that way you can test your code locally, commit your module to the repository and push it to your live site in a manageable way. Furthermore, you can also remove your module from core_resource and reinstall it quite easily.

Your module can also be useful for general utility code, e.g. any other small snippets of code associated with your theme (that do not deserve yet another module).

If you run the above 'module creator' you will have placeholder files for your install script. Furthermore, your work will be documented in your commit log and the next developer will be able to see how the catalogue structure has been modified.

Comment: You are absolutely right but i needed a quick solution. Once I am done with site I am working on I will defiantly learn how to make proper dedicated modules.